# Bean Property dataSource Not Writable in Spring + Hibernate 3 (Reposted due to unable to add more codes)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am having problem of pasting on my previous thread.
Following is the question I had asked earlier:

```
package com.springhibernate.example;

import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public class HibernateDaoImpl {
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public int getCircleCount(){

        String hql = "Select count(*) from Circle";
        Query query = getSessionFactory().openSession().createQuery(hql);
        return (int) query.uniqueResult();

    }

    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

}
```

I am having following error :

```
Invalid property 'dataSource' of bean class [com.springhibernate.example.HibernateDaoImpl]: Bean property 'dataSource' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1385)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1107)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
        at com.springhibernate.example.SpringHibernateDemo.main(SpringHibernateDemo.java:13)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'dataSource' of bean class [com.springhibernate.example.HibernateDaoImpl]: Bean property 'dataSource' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:1057)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:920)
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:76)
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:58)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1382)
        ... 13 more
```

Thanks guys for your help....

Comment: Show us your context-configuration file too

Comment: Matin, its in the previous post...

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, this error could be two issues:

1) As Ale Zalazar said: no datasource tag on xml (Writer or Reader)

2) You must implement on Reader or writer (where you need datasource object):

`public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}`

or something like:

```
private HibernateOperations hibernateTemplate;

public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.hibernateTemplate = new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory);
}
```

Depending on how you are implementing.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You dont have "dataSource" in your `HibernateDaoImpl` 
You should use something like this to make your Dao work. That is my example setup for datasource and session factory. And be careful because that thing is case sensitive:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
    <property name="url"
        value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:9999/yourDBname" />
    <property name="username" value="userName" />
    <property name="password" value="passsssssword" />
</bean>

<!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
<bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.people.net.model.PersonPersistenceModel</value>
            <value>com.people.net.model.EmailPersistenceModel</value>
            <value>com.people.net.model.AddressPersistenceModel</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="managerDAO" class="com.people.net.dao.ManagerDaoImpl">
    <property name="sFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

"sFactory" is the "sessionFactory" (must be the property name of the SessionFactory you are using in your Data Access Object- DAO)

Answer (score -1):

You must not use

```
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
```

in your bean defintion for HibernateDaoImpl in applicationContext.xml.

If you want to do so, you must provide a setDataSource method in HibernateDaoImpl with the corresponding property dataSource.

Comment: Ale tnx, but what should i use to replace it?

Comment: You don't need to replace it, it's enough to have the dataSource in the sessionFactory definition.